# SQL: Does a temp table return different results when called later if the base table changes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have the following:

```
--Section 1
SELECT * INTO #TEMP1 FROM TABLEA

--Section 2
/*more code here*/

--Section 3
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1
```

During the processing of Section 2, `TABLEA` changes significantly. At Section 3, will my temp table return the results of the original `SELECT INTO` or will it now return the current results from the table?

Comment: return the results of the original SELECT INTO

Comment: A temp table is a table like any other, and despite the table itself being temporary, its contents have permanency. It's not a view, or a synonym, or a common table expression (all of which do "change" their contents depending on what's in the table they're wrapping).

Comment: Wouldn't this be a lot simpler to just test it yourself instead of waiting for people on the internet to give you a response...which you should confirm anyway.

Comment: @SeanLange I have my own answer from my own testing (that the results are permanently stored into `#TEMP1`), but I wanted to confirm with other experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TaPaKaHUA stated, the data in `#TEMP1` would not change. It is persisted. It's not like a *pointer* in some programming languages that only reference a memory location. You could test this easily though, by running `select * from #TEMP1` before, and after section 2 of your code and you'll see the data is identical. You'll want to use an `order by` though so the data is returned in the same order, making comparing more easy. Otherwise, the data would or could be returned in an arbitrary order. [More on that in this blog post if you are interested.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Answer (score 1):

A temp table has no link or "knowledge" of how it got populated. Indeed, `SELECT ... INTO` is only *one* means of populating a temp table. It can be populated by multiple different statements, have some of its data `UPDATE`d or `DELETE`d, etc.

It doesn't care where the data came from, it just stores the rows you insert into it. In most respects, it's just like any other table.

---

If you want something that "stores" a query rather than a set of results (that is, if you had wanted it to always reflect the current state), you can get something like that by defining a cursor (with appropriate options set so that it is a dynamic cursor).

But almost always, a cursor is the wrong answer to *whatever* question is asked, and it's not directly usable in a later query in the same way that a temp table is.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A table is a snapshot of when it is created -- unless you have explicitly changed the contents with DML ("data modification language", such as `insert`, `delete`, `update`, `truncate`).

If you want something that changes with the base table, then use a view:

```
create v_tableA as
    select a.* 
    from TABLEA a;
```

This will be recalculated when called, so it "changes" with the base table(s).